# Create mutable iterator in nightly build after mut_iter removed

Tags: rust

I downloaded the nightly build of Rust and attempted to build my code, but interestingly enough I realized `mut_iter()` no longer exists. What was the reason for removing the ability to create mutable iterators for strings? I have the function:

```
//invert hex picture, this is used in the print_bitmap function
//  to save space and break apart one large code base.
pub fn invert_ascii_hex_string(line: &mut [std::ascii::Ascii]) {
  for c in line.mut_iter() {
    *c = match c.to_char() {
      'x' => ' ',
       _  => 'x'
    }.to_ascii();
  }
}
```

and now I'm not sure how to go about accomplishing this without a mutable iterator. What could I now use to still iterate through the list and change each value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `iter_mut()` instead of `mut_iter()`

Comment: I'm not sure how I missed that on the doc site